# how to split the sentence into multiple sentence based on multiple condition regex?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the below sentences. I need to split the sentences into multiple sentences if the sentence has dot or a matched word.

Sentence 1: There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://uri.org/:Message. The InnerException message with data contract name 'enumStatus:' is not expected.

Expected result:

```
senetences =    1. There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://uri.org/:vMessage.
                2. The InnerException message with data contract name 'enumStatus:' is not expected.
```

Sentence 2: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated ORA-06512: at module1, line 48 ORA-06512: at line 1

Expected result:

```
senetences = 1. ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
             2. ORA-06512: at module1, line 48
             3. ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I am using below regex to split the sentences.

```
 sentences = re.split(r'(?<=\w\.)\s|ORA-[0-9]{1,8}', input)
```

Issue here is, for the first case, if any word followed by dot is working fine.
For the second case, I am able to split the sentence. I have 2 issues.

1. It is removing the entire match word 'ORA-'.  But I need the entire word.
2. I am getting 4 sentences instead of 3 sentences.

   1. (first is empty since it has starting word ORA-)
   2. quoted string not properly terminated
   3. at module1, line 48
   4. at line 1

I need 3 sentences in this case.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex for splitting:

```sh
\s+(?=ORA-\d+)|(?<=\.)\s+(?=[A-Z])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TOo2wc/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\s+(?=ORA-\d+)`: Match 1+ whitespace if that is followed by `ORA-` and 1+ digits
- `|`: OR
- `(?<=\.)\s+(?=[A-Z])`: Match 1+ whitespace if that is preceded by a dot and followed by an uppercase letter

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/OAr0va)

**Code:**

```sh
import re
arr = ["There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://uri.org/:Message. The InnerException message with data contract name 'enumStatus:' is not expected.", "ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated ORA-06512: at module1, line 48 ORA-06512: at line 1"]

rx = re.compile(r'\s+(?=\bORA-\d+)|(?<=\.)\s+(?=[A-Z])')
for i in arr: print (rx.split(i))
```

**Output:**

```sh
['There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://uri.org/:Message.', "The InnerException message with data contract name 'enumStatus:' is not expected."]
['ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated', 'ORA-06512: at module1, line 48', 'ORA-06512: at line 1']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\w\.)\s|(ORA-[0-9]{1,8})
```

You can try this and replace by `\n\1`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/8yvUuZ/1/

```
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(?<=\w\.)\s|(ORA-[0-9]{1,8})"

test_str = ("ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated ORA-06512: at module1, line 48 ORA-06512: at line 1\n"
    "There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://uri.org/:Message. The InnerException message with data contract name 'enumStatus:' is not expected.")

subst = "\\n\\1"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```